# Writing data in native heap to disk in Android

Tags: android, memory, java-native-interface

I am doing JPEG encoding of RGB data in native code and the final JPEG encoded data is available in native byte array. What are the efficient ways for writing this data to disk? There is no more processing to be done on this output.

Some options I could think of are:

- Copy the data between Java Native boundary and write the data to disk using standard Android Approach.
- Write data to disk in the native code itself. But with Android Q moving to scoped storage access, I have been writing data via MediaStore. Can we write to MediaStore from native code?
- Allocate a ByteBuffer in Java code, pass it to the native code for writing, then once the encoding is over, flush the data in ByteBuffer to disk. This seems fair, but I'd prefer doing memory management in native layer than depending on GC in java layer.

I have strong feeling some of my assumptions are wrong, please call them out for my learning.

Comment: If you look at the table in https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage , where does your use case fit in?

Comment: My use-case is Media. The example you provided in the answer seems very helpful - I am going to try that one out.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are only for consumption by *your* application, you can just write to your applications cache (`getExternalCacheDir`) or data (`getExternalFilesDir`) directory.

If you want to make them accessible to other files you can use the MediaStore framework as you hinted at. You can adapt [this example](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media#add-item) at the official documentation into the following:

```kotlin
val resolver = applicationContext.contentResolver

val imagesCollection = MediaStore.Images.Media
        .getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)

val imageDetails = ContentValues().apply {
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "fancy_image.jpg")
    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
}

val imageContentUri = resolver.insert(imagesCollection, imageDetails)

resolver.openFileDescriptor(imageContentUri, "w", null).use { pfd ->
    int fd = pfd.getFd
    // this would be your native implementation. it should `write()` to the fd or 
    // call `fdopen` and then `fwrite`. The `use` block will automatically call 
    // `close` for you.
    native_writeFile(fd)
}

// Now that we're finished, release the "pending" status, and allow other apps
// to see the image
imageDetails.clear()
imageDetails.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
resolver.update(imageContentUri, imageDetails, null, null)
```